# My contacts are disappearing on their own

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I have Iphone 7. Today, I got a call from my friend but instead of the saved name (yes his number was saved in my contacts) his number was displayed. So, after talking to him I tried checking why the name was not displayed, I found that his contact was no more in my contacts (only "siri found in apps).

What could be the reason? Is there any chance that I got something malicious in my Iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal experience, the issue might be an iCloud syncing problem or somehow the main group in your Contacts app has been unselected.

To check to see if all of your Contact groups are selected, open the Contacts app and tap on the groups button on the top left corner.  You should see a checkmark next to the groups that are selected.

If this is not the issue, then you might want to go to iCloud.com to see if your contacts are at least stored on the cloud.

To answer your last question, yes there is a chance that something malicious could be occurring but it is very improbable unless someone managed to hack your Apple ID.

Comment: You know the new contacts that I save on my phone don’t get uploaded to iCloud (by mobile/cellular data) and when I connect the iPhone to WiFi then only then get uploaded. Is this related to that?

Comment: It very well could be related, but contacts should be uploaded to the cloud over cellular data, not just WiFi.  You could check to make sure that the Contacts app under cellular is toggled on in the Cellular section of the settings app.  But other than that, I'm not sure why it would not be syncing over a cellular connection.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it was off for mobile data. You’re really awesome.

Comment: Yesterday, I followed your suggestions but I don’t know why “Groups” is not available on my IPhone 7 (I updated it yesterday to IOS 13.6). Here is the [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AiIjxokQyPYds7Z94rgg604DzkFXNHY7/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: Hmmm. It appears that means that you don't have any groups created.